# Two different pages get clipped with login and signUp page display in android xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, responsive-design

Login And SignUp Screen

[image]

How to implement and write xml file like this image? Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.90"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- put your Login page content ,email
         ,password Edittext and other button here.
         -->

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:background="@drawable/lay_background"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/signUp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:weightSum="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

lay_background.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item
            android:left="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:top="0dp"
            android:bottom="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
                <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

and `onClick()` of textview open your signup activity this is another approach.Try this I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks you.This is almost right my question answer but I want to use fold and unfold current fragment , clearfocus on this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using Viewpager/Recyclerview,

I have used Recyclerview with the snap feature. My project requirement is, the next module button should be partially visible part of the first screen. So I have used recyclerview and kept the Item size bit smaller than screen width. So that the next item visible partially. As soon as clicking the button it will smoothscrool to next item.